# How do I configure elastic beanstalk to use https with an ACM certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used the AWS certificate manager to create an ACM certificate.

I followed this guide: https://medium.com/@arcdigital/enabling-ssl-via-aws-certificate-manager-on-elastic-beanstalk-b953571ef4f8#.kjh1mqdzq to configure the load balancer using the aws cli.

When I look at my load balancers, I now see 443(HTTPS, ACM Certification:[arn]) forwarding to 80 (HTTP) under Port Configuration

However, if I type in https in my browser I get the "your connection is not private" message from chrome.

Is there another step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given this info, but I'm assuming you have a CNAME for www.yourdomain.com that is resolving to loadbalancer.amazonaws.com.

You are getting the ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error because you are using a CNAME which is resolving to loadbalancer.amazonaws.com. Since your certificate is for www.yourdomain.com, it is giving a valid error. CNAME and Alias operate slightly differently. With a CNAME the traffic is not a valid alias of your domain so if you're trying to secure it, you will receive errors. However, when you create an A record for www and alias that to loadbalancer.amazonaws.com now any traffic from loadbalancer.amazonaws.com on www.yourdomain.com is valid traffic for your domain and you will no longer have those errors.

In order to terminate secure traffic for www.yourdomain.com at loadbalancer.amazonaws.com you need to have an A record that will alias there. Unfortunately, ELB's only provide a DNS entry, no IP address, but many DNS providers (ie GoDaddy) will not allow you to have a DNS A record that is aliased to a DNS address; they require you to alias to an IP address. Which makes life a bit more complex.

There are a couple ways to accomplish this (URL forwarding and masking is not supported by SSL), but the easiest solution is to use Route 53. Use of Route 53 doesn't require you to register or transfer your name to AWS and a hosted zone is just $0.50/month per domain.

To use Route 53 follow these steps:

- Create a Hosted Zone for yourdomain.com. When you create a Hosted Zone in Route 53 it will complete a few default records (like an A, NS, and SOA records). Note the NS records as you'll need them later.
- Next copy your existing zone file entries (like MX records) from your current DNS provider to your new hosted zone.
- When it comes to a record that you want to direct traffic for to your ELB you'll enter the name, say www, and then just below the type option field you'll see a radio option that says "Alias: yes no". - - When you select yes, the value field will disappear and you'll see an option that says "Alias Target: Enter Target Name". When you click that field you'll receive a drop down list of resources in your account that you can alias to. Simply select your load balancer.
- Click create, and you're done with Route 53.
  Now that all your dns records are copied over, and you'll go to your registrar and change the nameservers to the ones that Route 53 provided you.

Now Route 53 is handling your DNS for you. And loadbalancer.amazonaws.com is a valid alias of www.mydomain.com. Since loadbalancer.amazonaws.com is now a valid alias of www.yourdomain.com when you visit www.yourdomain.com your ELB at loadbalancer.amazonaws.com will terminate the traffic as www.yourdomain.com and your error will be resolved.